# Python/Selemium - How to modify to resolve this error name 'lp' is not defined

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver

I have this code and it works fine. Page 1:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pytest
import unittest
from pages.home.login_page import LoginPage


class LoginTests(unittest.TestCase):


    def testinvalidlogin(self):
          baseURL = "http://www.tutorialsninja.com/demo/"
          driver = webdriver.Chrome()
          driver.maximize_window()
          driver.implicitly_wait(3)
          driver.get(baseURL)
          lp = LoginPage(driver)


        lp.login("knoppix123@gmail.com", "sdsdd$WW")

        invalidlogin = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible']")
        if invalidlogin is not None:
           print("Invalid login Test succefully completed")
```

Page 2:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class LoginPage():

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver


    def login(self, username, password):


        accountButton = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'My Account')]")
        accountButton.click()
        loginbutton = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//body/nav[@id='top']/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[2]/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1]")
        loginbutton.click()

        enterlogin = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-email")
        enterlogin.send_keys(username)

        enterpassword = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-password")
        enterpassword.send_keys(password)


        clicklogin = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn btn-primary']")
        clicklogin.click()
```

I have added setUp to run website every time:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pytest
import unittest
from pages.home.login_page import LoginPage


class LoginTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        baseURL = "http://www.tutorialsninja.com/demo/"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        driver.get(baseURL)
        lp = LoginPage(driver)


    def testinvalidlogin(self):
       
        lp.login("knoppix123@gmail.com", "a1asdsds")

        invalidlogin = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible']")
        if invalidlogin is not None:
           print("Invalid login Test succefully completed")
```

And not I have FAILED tests/home/login_test.py::LoginTests::testinvalidlogin - NameError: name 'lp' is not defined

Comment: You probably want these bound to the class on `setUp` like `self.lp = LoginPage(driver)` and `self.driver = webdriver...`. Otherwise, it's looking for a local variable `lp` that isn't defined in the function's scope

Answer (score 0):

In `testinvalidlogin` you are calling `lp.login("knoppix123@gmail.com", "a1asdsds")`, but `lp` doesn't exist in the scope of that method. You would have to properly define `lp` as an attribute of the class in `setUp`.

```py
    ...
    def setUp(self):
        baseURL = "http://www.tutorialsninja.com/demo/"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        driver.get(baseURL)
        self.lp = LoginPage(driver)


    def testinvalidlogin(self):
       
        self.lp.login("knoppix123@gmail.com", "a1asdsds")
        ...
```

Comment: that works, Thank you)